# Why are there no dependency arrows from the client to the receiver and invoker in the command-pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, uml

In OOP a dependency exists when a class uses the keyword `new` to create an instance. Regarding [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) the UML-notation shows a dependency via an arrow that has a dashed line:

[image]

The website https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern shows code and its UML for the Command pattern. The code on this website has a client-class (I think it's the `MainApp`) which contains three times the keyword `new` to create an instance for the receiver, command and invoker.

```
// Client
class MainApp
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Entry point into console application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create receiver, command, and invoker
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver(); // <- no dashed arrow in UML
        Command command = new ConcreteCommand(receiver); // <- dashed arrow in UML
        Invoker invoker = new Invoker(); // <- no dashed arrow in UML

        // [...]
    }
}

abstract class Command
{
    // [...]
}

class ConcreteCommand : Command
{
    public ConcreteCommand(Receiver receiver) : base(receiver)
    {
        // [...]
    }

    // [...]
}

class Receiver
{
    // [...]
}

class Invoker
{
    // [...]
}
```

You can find the full code here: https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Why does the UML on this [website](https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) only show a dependency of the client to the concrete `command`? Because the client also uses the keyword `new` on receiver and invoker. I also expect dependency arrows to receiver and invoker in the UML.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the code belongs to the diagram. See here: https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: @qwerty_so: I have added the main code snippets now from  dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: Are you complaining because you created the diagram with a tool?

Comment: If so, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861006/why-two-class-is-not-connected-in-classdiagram

Comment: @qwerty_so: Sorry I were not precise. The question is, why the website https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern (where I have copied the UML) and other sources show an UML without the dependencies.

Comment: Then you should go with the answer of  https://stackoverflow.com/users/4105662/konstantin-peshekhonov . UML diagrams in books are often reduced if not wrong. Client-Receiver is already associated, so no dependency needed. Invoker should have a dependency, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just a simple example and in real world you should get invoker & receiver injected by DI container. But the command is always specified by calling code (your code knows about specific ConcreteCommand anyway)

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

From a design pattern perspective, it doesn't matter how the `Command` object gets from the `Client` who creates it to the `Invoker` who executes it. If the `Client` directly passes it to the `Invoker` (and thus has a direct dependency) that's fine. If the `Client` persists the `Command` into a database and the `Invoker` later retrieves it, that is also fine.

From a UML perspective, there is no line between `Client` and `Invoker` because there doesn't have to be. Adding that line might imply a dependency was necessary.

From a code example perspective, instantiating everything in one main class is simple and straightforward, so it's understandable why you see it implemented that way in numerous tutorials. Just remember that you may see the pattern implemented somewhat differently in the real world, and still following the UML.

Comment: It's not a question about the design pattern, but about the application of the latter. But maybe that's just what is causing the confusion here.

Comment: The UML originates from the GoF design patterns book, so I interpret it as a pattern question. It could be noted that since the book was published in 1994, it predates the UML spec; but since we're questioning the absence of a line, the date doesn't matter so much. Ultimately, the answer is that the missing link is by design, and not an accidental omission.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a user or client that uses your pattern from somewhere in your code. some techniques like DI uses another way to create your object and put it in the ram and inject it into your code.

For this reason and for simplifying in all UML that shows the Gof-patterns shows the client that uses "New keyword" in your code to make Object.

So it just uses New keyword to show us using in the client. in the real world, we use DI to inject our dependency in classes.

There is also another valuable reference that you can see:

[Command Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command)